# Error executing git command on Oracle Linux server, returns error code 501

Tags: git, http, oraclelinux

I am trying to execute the following git command on my server (Oracle Linux 6):

```
git ls-remote -h https://<my-repo-path>.git
```

But it throws the following error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 501 Method Not Implemented while accessing https://<my-repo-path>.git/info/refs
```

Git version is 1.7.1 and I am unable to update it to any latest version (unless I built it from source which I am reluctant to do at this point). Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not necessarily a Git one, but one from the remote HTTP server, which return a custom error message (not seen in Git itself): looking at the logs of that server might yield more clues.

In the meantime, if possible, you could try using an SSH URL, provided you can make your public SSH key registered on the server side, on the account managing those Git repos.

Then this would work: `git ls-remote <remoteAccount>@<server>:/path/to/git/repo`

Or: if the repo is on the *same* server as the one you are executing your command, you can use its path directly:

```
git ls-remote -h /path/to/git/repo
```

But upgrading first remain a good option, which the [OP saikat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594823/saikat) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990253/error-executing-git-command-on-oracle-linux-server-returns-error-code-501/54996314#comment96755245_54996314):

> Issue solved after upgrading the git version

Comment: Looks like my bitbucket server does not support this - `ssh: connect to host <my-bitbucket-server> port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: @Saikat Is your Git server the same as the one you are running `git ls-remote`?

Comment: No it's different, I am now [installing git from source](https://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7) which I did not intend to do initially :P

Comment: Issue solved after upgrading the git version, thanks for your help @VonC